# Qual a diferença entre as duas estruturas dos arrays e seu laços de repetição em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loop

Gostaria de saber qual é o mais indicado para se trabalhar com arrays?

```
var meu_array = new Array(1, 2, 3);
var meu_array = [1, 2, 3];
```

Existe alguma diferença de performance entre os 6 casos apresentados
no uso de laço abaixo?

```
 // foreach 
    meu_array.forEach(function(valor, i){
        console.log(valor, i);
    }); 
 // for key associativa
    for (var i in meu_array) {
        console.log(meu_array[i], i);
    }
 // for valor associativo  
   var i = 0;
   for (value of meu_array) {
       console.log(value, i++);
   }
 // for interator
    for (var i=0; i<=meu_array.length; i++) {
        console.log(meu_array[i], i);
    }
 // while
    var i=0;
    while (i <= meu_array.length) {
          console.log(meu_array[i], i);
     i++;
    }
 // jquery
    $.each(meu_array, function(i, value) {
      console.log(value, i);
    });
```

Comment: Se quer saber sobre a performance de cada algoritmo desses, faça outra pergunta, não faça duas perguntas em uma só. E o que é a *tag* acme?

Comment: Também estou curioso sobre acme. Acho que ele quis escrever ecma, de ECMAScript. rs

Comment: rs...digitei errado.

Comment: Vai fazer a outra pergunta? Esta está muito esquisita, pergunta de array, depois fala de laços, são coisas distintas, separe elas. Respondi sobre o array porque era o que está no título. Se quer saber sobre os laços, faça a pergunta sobre eles. Se não quer, apenas retire esta parte da pergunta para não ficar confuso. Se vai fazer, eu já vou preparando a resposta.

Comment: Eu acredito que tudo pode ser respondido em uma única pergunta.

Comment: Não, não pode, são duas coisas completamente dissociadas. Nem você acredita já que eu não respondi a segunda parte e você aceitou minha resposta. Se vai insistir em manter isto como duas perguntas em uma eu vou votar para fechar como muito ampla. O que vai fazer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essencialmente não faz diferença prática. Eles criam o mesmo *array* e a performance será a mesma por ele. A performance pode ser um pouco melhor para o primeiro caso, mas **só na criação** e será muito pouca diferença para se importar. E isto depende de implementação da linguagem. Não conte com isto.

Existe uma diferença de performance pelo algoritmo usado em cada situação exemplificada, mas não porque o *array* foi criado de um jeito ou de outro.

A primeira forma é considerada confusa, porque se quiser criar um *array* com apenas um elemento, ele não fará o que você espera. Ele criará um *array* com a quantidade de elementos especificado e não um *array* com um elemento com aquele valor.

Além disto ela chamará o construtor que construirá o *array*. A segunda forma criará o *array* sem passar pelo construtor. Isto pode parecer dar no mesmo. Mas não há garantias na linguagem que isto seja verdade. É possível sobrescrever o método.

A recomendação geral é não usar o `Array()` a não ser que seja preciso mesmo e saiba o que está fazendo e porque está preferindo ele.

Comment: Concordo com você, no caso de evitar uso de instância do objeto Array, na verdade eu prefiro evitar o uso geral de array, gosto mais de trabalhar com objeto.

Comment: Não sei se faz diferença, o *array* é um objeto disfarçado.

Comment: na verdade o tipo do objeto que deveria ser array, é um objeto... javascript é muito bagunçado.

Comment: Olha isso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqhZZNUyVFM

Comment: Essas coisas são toscas e não levam a lugar algum. São fãs de uma linguagem falando mal de outra linguagem. O inverso também é sempre possível. Tudo existe por algum motivo.